# How to substitute $ for a parameter in Array Update Operators [Mongoose]

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongoose, operator-keyword

I have an apparently simple question, is it possible for me to replace the $ operator used to identify the index of an attribute array inside the mongoose for a variable that I have already passed as a parameter?

i.e. transform

```
$set: {"img.$]": req.params.imgUrl}
```

into something like

```
const indexDesired = req.params.indexParams // 0, 1 , 2

$set: {"img.indexDesired]": req.params.imgUrl}
```

thanks in advance for any and all help!